# What is the extension of Visual Code that it is possible to create a documentation template with automatic date update?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had a great extension to create documentation for my templated scripts.

When creating a new script and inserting the documentation, it already started with my author data, and with the date of creation. And every time I saved the file it automatically updated the @modify date.

After I formatted my computer, I lost that extension and never found it again.

The template I used was the following:

```
//==============================================================================
// TILE
//
// @author: Author Name
// @website: https://www.website.com/
// 
// Template text here
//
// @create date 2023-02-07 20:08:48
// @modify date 2023-02-10 02:39:45
//==============================================================================
```

Can anyone point me to an extension that does this?

"**Doxygen**" and "**Document This**" didn't work for me. Or maybe you didn't know how to use it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/

Comment: @starball 
?? I don't understand, what is this? My question has nothing to do with games. It's about extension for visual studio which uses template and updates data automatically. Didn't you read what I wrote?